# How to tell which ISO version you need?

Tags: updates, windows-10-v1511

It is looking like I will have to try running the Windows Fall update from USB as I have 2 machines here that are failing & rolling back when using the Windows Update version.

I have access to the Fall Update ISOs, even after they were pulled from the Microsoft servers today.

I am running, from System Information

```
* OS Name       Microsoft Windows 10 Pro  
* Version       10.0.10240 Build 10240  
* System Type   x64-based PC  
* Locale        United Kingdom
```

Does that mean I need
en-gb_windows_10_multiple_editions_version_1511_x64_dvd_7223718.iso
in order to make my own updater USB from the Media Creation Tool?

Comment: It should be as simple as selecting the same language version.  With 1511 .Windows 10 .ISO images contain both Professional and Home versions of Windows 10.  Specialized regional versions like Single Language and other feature limited regional images (N/K/etc) are still separate.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this site](http://microsoft-news.com/microsoft-pulls-the-plug-on-windows-10-november-update/), 10240 is the RTM build (July 2015). Windows versions with November update report as build 10586 ([source](http://www.komputerswiat.pl/nowosci/programy/2015/47/microsoft-wycofuje-windows-10-1511-z-media-creation-tool.aspx), in Polish).

Updated ISOs are marked with number 1511, so the one you have should be fine as long as the language and 32/64-bitness match.

Official updated ISOs have been pulled from publicly available sources, but they are still [available for MSDN subscribers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/aa336858.aspx).